# How to call Ruby method on user click?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple .erb file that creates a list of song names.

When the user clicks the name, I want a browser window to open and play that song in YouTube. My YouTube implementation is a quick hack, but to that happen you simply call

`YouTubeAPI.new(searchphrase)`

and pass it a string.

My question: how can I make the page respond to user input, so that when the user clicks on the song name it passes that song name as the value to my YouTubeAPI class method?

This is my small .erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Songs</h1>
<p>There are <%=Song.all.count%> in this playlist.</p>

<p><strong>All Songs:</strong></p>

<% Song.all.each do |song| %>
<li><a href = "songs/<%=song.name.downcase.gsub(/\s+/, "")%>.html">
  <%=song.name%></a></li>
<% end %>

<a href = "../index.html">Home</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your YouTubeAPI.new(searchphrase) method? Is it a javascript or a method in Rails server side?

Comment: It's definitely not JS, so I assume it's Rails server side.

Answer (score 0):

I see few approaches to this.

One is, of course, Ajax. Intercept this click with Javascript and send the song name to your controller. The controller can return the Youtube URL, and your javascript ajax callback can reload this.

Another thing to try is to replace the href to your site - you actually call your site with song name as parameter, and then your YOUtubeAPI will redirect the user to youtube.

One more option, rewrite this helper in Javascript and put it on the client.